# R: How to add a label on the right axis in a ggplot barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Suppose I create a ggplot barplot with this code:

```
mtcars$carb<-as.character(mtcars$carb)
mtcars$gear<-as.character(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$carb_labelright<-paste0("label_right",mtcars$carb)

#pelacolset
ggplot(mtcars, 
       #color by which to fill
       aes(fill=gear, 
           #y axis
           y=wt, 
           #x axis
           x=carb)) +
  #title and subtitle
  
  
  #barplot
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity",width=.8)+
  coord_flip()+
  

  #rotate x axis labels 90 degrees
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

The plot looks like this:
[image]

Now I would like to use the column carb_labelright to add the data on the right side of the bar plot. It should look like this:

[image]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find easiest to annotate with `geom_text` (you'll need a data frame) or with `annotate(geom = "text",...)`. Using annotate is usually safer, as `geom_text` likes to create a label for each row (which is fine when you use carefully prepared data frames for annotation).

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars$carb<-as.character(mtcars$carb)
mtcars$gear<-as.character(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$carb_labelright<-paste0("label_right",mtcars$carb)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  # use geom_col, a convenience wrapper for geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  geom_col(aes(fill=gear, y=wt, x=carb), 
           position="fill", width=.8) +
  # you have to turn clipping off
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = unique(mtcars$carb),
           label = unique(mtcars$carb_labelright),
           y = 1, hjust = 0) +
  # you need to increase the legend's margin and make it "transparent"
  # otherwise you will cover some labels. 
  theme(legend.margin = margin(l = 1, unit = "inch"),
        legend.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks, this works, but is there an option without creating a new dataframe? in my application it would be best to just use the column as it is...

Comment: @Olympia updated

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into the problem of discrete axes not supporting secondary scales (see related [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3171) on the ggplot2 repo). I solved it by writing [a manual guide](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/PositionGuides.html#manual-axes-1) myself that does allow me to make secondary axes with discrete scales. In the code below, we use `ggh4x::guide_axis_manual()` in combination with an rlang/purrr lambda function to format the labels.  (Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x).

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.1

mtcars$carb<-as.character(mtcars$carb)
mtcars$gear<-as.character(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$carb_labelright<-paste0("label_right",mtcars$carb)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, 
       aes(fill = gear, y = carb, x = wt)) +
  geom_col(position="fill", width=.8)

p + guides(
  y.sec = ggh4x::guide_axis_manual(
    labels = ~ paste0("label_right_", .x)
  )
)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can give the labels as a character vector directly too.

```r
p + guides(
  y.sec = ggh4x::guide_axis_manual(
    labels = sort(unique(mtcars$carb_labelright))
  )
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: great solution!